# Review explanation for deleted post

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Is there a way to get review answers explained?

I failed the following audit and am trying to understand what I did wrong. I answered `Needs Editing` based on not being able to find a direct duplicate, and the fact that the question could be a valid question, if it didn't have the overuse of CapsLock and explained why command prompt was not wanted (maybe some Group Policy restriction).

**[Audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/17673397) (screenshot included below in case the link goes dead)**

I assume the question and some deleted answer were spam together based on the comments, but at the review time I could not see any answers, so I judged the question by itself, should I have flagged it based on comments saying it was spam without evidence?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 22):

What happened here is the user posted this question (and a subsequent answer) in order to promote a video they have on youtube to do what they ask in the question.  The answer they posted was

[image]

So, the mod came in, nuked the answer (spam flagged it which auto deletes it) and then deleted the question.  When they deleted the question it also had at spam flag on it so it applied that as well when the mod deleted it.  This is what made it come up as an audit.

This is not the best audit as it relies on context that you can't know from the review queue.

Comment: Is there anything I should have done differently, or any changes (letting people see deleted items when reviewing?) that being made to solve this?

Comment: @jrtapsell I don't think you needed to do anything different.  You just got caught by a bad audit.  This will happen from time to time.

Comment: @jrtapsell some will argue you could have acted on the comments and decided to open another tab and investigate the post, but that's not quite how reviews should work (besides - if the answer was deleted you wouldn't have seen it anyway) - so it looks like a genuine (albeit short) question. I've lifted the review ban that this one caused.

Comment: Was it neccessary to mark the question as spam? It sounds like it would still be useful to to others if it got answered

Comment: @Pureferret I'm fine with the mod wiping it out.  If someone legitimately has the question they can ask it.  Since it was a spam seed I'm not sure if the spam flags should have been cleared or not.